# JavaMail not retrieving email properly

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

My email program is not retrieving mail properly.

Before it used to display something like javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart@787171
now that I solved it using BodyPart() it won't retrieve emails it already retrieved. The funny thing is that the emails aren't deleted from my account, it just won't count or shows them again. Also, this is a long shot but is there anything I can do so if it contains an attachment it will show the text but ignore the attachment?

Output:
0. Exit
1. Switch User
2. Compose email
3. Read email
4. Change Details
5. Add user
6. Remove User
3

### Number of emails: 1

Email Number: 1
Subject: 
From: XXXX XXXX 
Text: 
test

1. Exit
2. Switch User
3. Compose email
4. Read email
5. Change Details
6. Add user
7. Remove User
   3
   Number of emails: 0
8. Exit
9. Switch User
10. Compose email
11. Read email
12. Change Details
13. Add user
14. Remove User

this is the code behind the email retrieval:

```
 import javax.mail.internet.*;

 import java.util.Properties;
 import javax.mail.*;
 import java.util.*;

 public class CheckingMails {

 public static void check(String user,
  String password) 
  {String host = "pop.gmail.com";
        String storetype="pop3";
      try {

  //create properties field
  Properties properties = new Properties();

  properties.put("mail.pop3.host", host);
  properties.put("mail.pop3.port", "995");
  properties.put("mail.pop3.starttls.enable", "true");
  Session emailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

  //create the POP3 store object and connect with the pop server
  Store store = emailSession.getStore("pop3s");

  store.connect(host, user, password);

  //create the folder object and open it
  Folder emailFolder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
  emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

  // retrieve the messages from the folder in an array and print it
  Message[] messages = emailFolder.getMessages();
  System.out.println("Number of emails: " + messages.length);

  for (int i = 0, n = messages.length; i < n; i++) {
     Message message = messages[i];
     System.out.println("---------------------------------");
     System.out.println("Email Number: " + (i + 1));
     System.out.println("Subject: " + message.getSubject());
     System.out.println("From: " + message.getFrom()[0]);
     MimeMultipart mmp = (MimeMultipart) message.getContent();
     System.out.println("Text: ");

        for (int xyz=1; xyz<mmp.getCount(); xyz++) {

           System.out.println(mmp.getBodyPart(i).getContent());
        }



  }

  //close the store and folder objects
  emailFolder.close(false);
  store.close();

  } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (MessagingException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {

  String host = "pop.gmail.com";// change accordingly
  String mailStoreType = "pop3";
  String username = "yourmail@gmail.com";// change accordingly
  String password = "*****";// change accordingly

  //check(host, mailStoreType, username, password);

   }

}
```

Comment: Ok so it works properly again once i switched it to imap the attachment thing is still an issue tho

Comment: If it still doesn't work, read the [JavaMail FAQ](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ) and then post a new question.